# É possivel alterar o tiutlo do select sem interferir no que está sendo mostrado nos options?

Tags: html5, react, html-select, selected-option

Eu tenho uma array de objetos que é mais ou menos assim:

```
const array = [
  nome: "Imovel 1",
  complemento: [
    nome: "1 andar"
  ]
]
```

Eu utilizo ele para popular um select com options assim:

```
<select
      required
      name="complements"
      id="complements"
    >
      {array.map(property => (
        <>
          <option disabled={!!property.nome} value={property.nome}>
            {property.nome}
          </option>
          {property.complementos.map(complement => (
            <option key={complement.nome} value={complement.nome}>
              {complement.nome}
            </option>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </select>
```

Preciso no "display" do select apareça o nome do imovel seguido do nome do complemento. Como por exemplo "Imovel 1 - 1 andar"

Existe alguma forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver o seu problema:

```
const properties = [
    {
      name: "Imovel 1",
      complements: [{ name: "1 andar" }]
    },
    {
      name: "Imovel 2",
      complements: [{ name: "2 andar" }]
    }
  ];

  <select required name="complements" id="complements">
    {properties.map((property) =>
      property.complements.map(({ name }) => (
        <option key={name} value={name}>
          {property.name} - {name}
        </option>
      ))
    )}
  </select>
```

Se você deseja mostrar outros complementos além do nome. Considere o o trecho abaixo:

```
const properties = [
    {
      name: "Imovel 1",
      complements: [{ name: "1 andar", color: "Blue" }]
    },
    {
      name: "Imovel 2",
      complements: [{ name: "2 andar", color: "Red" }]
    }
  ];

  <select required name="complements" id="complements">
    {properties.map((property) =>
      property.complements.map(({ name, color }) => (
        <option key={name} value={name}>
          {property.name} - {name} - {color}
        </option>
      ))
    )}
  </select>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).